# Difference between Ionic CLI version and Ionic Version

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic-cli, ionic-vue

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the Ionic Version and Ionic CLI version? I heard that the latest version of Ionic is ionic 5. is it possible I can create an Ionic-Vue app with ionic 5?

These are the details:

Ionic:

- Ionic CLI : 6.11.0

Utility:

- cordova-res : not installed
- native-run  : not installed

System:

- NodeJS : v12.18.3
- npm    : 6.14.6
- OS     : Windows 10

C:\MobileAppProjects\reddit-clone>vue --version
@vue/cli 4.5.4

Comment: I assume this is similar to the difference between Vue and Vue CLI. The former is a JavaScript UI framework and the latter is a command-line utility

Comment: The above comment from Phil is absolutely correct.. CLI and frameworks have different version.. As far as using Vue with Ionic, it is still in Beta phase. Refer this official link https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/overview